# PTIJ: B'nai Yisra'el and Kashi in the desert

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In Devarim 9:27, Moshe says to G-d:

> אל תפן אל קשי העם הזה
>
> Don't pay attention to this people's [Kashi](https://www.kashi.com/)

Kashi has become a popular brand of cereal and nutrition bars in the U.S. I've had a few types of cereals, and they are tasty and nutritious as well.

I had no idea that Kashi even existed in the desert. Where did B'nai Yisra'el get the ingredients to make Kashi in the desert? Moreso, why does Moshe ask God not to pay any attention to it? I would think that Moshe would have been proud of the Kashi and asked for God's approval as well as the Divine *hashgacha* (kosher certification) on Kashi.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: The Gemara talks about Kashi a lot too, except they use the Aramaic variation of the word: קשיא. Also, do you think Kashi might have something to do with Rashi?

Comment: @ezra Rash"i is *rashi tevot* for *ra kashi* - meaning kashi that spoiled.

Answer (score 2):

In [Devarim 11:11](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Devarim/11.11#e0n7), Moshe says that Eretz Yisrael is an ארץ הרים ובקעות, a land of hills and valleys.  One of those valleys is the "[Nature Valley](https://www.naturevalley.com)", so in order that Benei Yisrael not become complacent with [Kashi](https://www.kashi.com/our-foods/bars), Hashem told Moshe not to pay attention to it, and rather to promote Nature Valley, as he does in the above Passuk.

(This fits in very well with the stories in the Torah relating to the Benei Yisrael being happy in the Midbar and not wanting the wonderful foods of Eretz Yisrael.)

Edit:  Now that I have looked at the context of the Passuk, it fits right in:

> **פֶּן יֹאמְרוּ הָאָרֶץ אֲשֶׁר הוֹצֵאתָנוּ מִשָּׁם מִבְּלִי יְכֹלֶת י"י לַהֲבִיאָם אֶל הָאָרֶץ אֲשֶׁר דִּבֶּר לָהֶם** וּמִשִּׂנְאָתוֹ אוֹתָם הוֹצִיאָם לַהֲמִתָם בַּמִּדְבָּר.